# How to convert camera capture into PDF and display using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to convert camera captured image (ex:receipt) to pdf file and display the converted pdf file in the app ? I have already implement capture image and display it as a image in following code,

```
class PreviewImageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imagePath;
  PreviewImageScreen({this.imagePath});

  @override
  _PreviewImageScreenState createState() => _PreviewImageScreenState();
}

class _PreviewImageScreenState extends State<PreviewImageScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Preview'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Image.file(File(widget.imagePath), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  } 
}
```

I'm new to flutter so can anyone please help me to do this task with an example